# ref with String in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models

```
 var Passenger = mongoose.model('passengers', new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            ref: 'users'
        },
        company: String,
        baggage: String,
        note: String,
        owner: String
    }));


    var User = mongoose.model('users', new Schema({
        username: String,
        first: String,
        last: String,
        email: String,
        password: String
    }));
```

I really would like to get a full user instead of a passenger with a username.  I thought ref and populate would be the way to do this.

```
Trip.find({
        request: true
    }).populate('flights.users').exec(function (err, trips) {

});
```

The top level document is Trip and Flights is an array under Trips and Passengers is an array under Flights.

Is this not possible.  Would I have to give my users all ID's instead?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Drew, how did you solve this?

Comment: Any solution? There seems to be no example usage anywhere including in mongoose doc even though it's hinted you can use String, Number, or Buffer as ref. Here

```Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs. However, you should use ObjectId unless you are an advanced user and have a good reason for doing so.``

Answer (score 1):

```
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no example usage anywhere including in the mongoose doc even though it's hinted you can use String, Number, or Buffer as ref. Here

`Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs. However, you should use ObjectId unless you are an advanced user and have a good reason for doing so.`

**An Alternative Workaround**
You could create a virtual for the field and populate that instead

```
var Passenger = mongoose.model('passengers', new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            ref: 'users'
        },
        company: String,
        baggage: String,
        note: String,
        owner: String
    }));


    var User = mongoose.model('users', new Schema({
        username: String,
        first: String,
        last: String,
        email: String,
        password: String
    }))

// this will add userObj field to your query result which will contain an array of users
Passenger.virtual('usersObj', {
 ref: 'users',
 localField: 'username',
 foreignField: 'username',
justOne: false,
})

// populate usersObj instead of users
Trip.find({
        request: true
    }).populate('flights.usersObj').exec(function (err, trips) {

});
```